# Rails: including JS only if a certain condition is met

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to include a piece of JS on every page, but only if `session` is set a certain way.

I've got a sidebar with a timer button in it. The sidebar (`layouts/_sidebar.html.erb`) is included on every page's layout once the user logs in.

Click the timer button once, and the timer starts. `LogsController#start_from_button` records the click event time in `session[:timer_start]`.

Click the button again, and `LogsController#finish_from_button` records the second click time in `session[:timer_finish]`. Then it renders a form for a new `Log`, with **START** and **FINISH** fields pre-filled with the `session` data. Finally, it clears the above `session` values.

Unfortunately, upon page refresh, the timer resets completely. I don't want that to happen. I want it to keep going until the user clicks the button a second time.

My first fix was checking the timer status in `ApplicationController` before every action. Then, if `session[:timer_start]` isn't `nil`, I might include the requisite JS to make the timer continue from `session[:timer_start]`. But the only way I know to do that is pretty ugly:

```
# application_controller.rb

before_action :check_timer_status
...
def check_timer_status
  if session[:timer_start]
    # include page-specific JS
  end
end
```

I also would like the templates to display as normal.

A) If this seems hacky, what's a better way of accomplishing this, or

B) If it's not too hacky, how might I be able to include the page-specific JS from that controller action?

Comment: Of course the timer will rest. That's why a session is a session - it is reset every time you restart the page or open/close the browser. Perhaps you should try cookie/local storage.

Comment: local storage looks like a tool you should use for this - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Did the solution work?

Comment: Your first comment here helped me immensely, though I ended up going a different route than your answer suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using cookies, and checked for them exclusively on the client side. Cookies were preferable to `localStorage` in my case because down the development road I may want to check cookie values server-side, and `localStorage` won't let me do that.

```
// Every page change, check if user has previously
// clicked the timelog start button but not the 
// timelog finish button.
// If so, start the timer from when the user first
// clicked the button.
if(isCookie('start_time') || $start_time) {
    timerRunningDisplay();
    activateTimer();            
}

// When user clicks timelog start button,
// start timer and save the click time in cookies.
  $(document).on("click", '#start-timelog', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    timerRunningDisplay();
    activateTimer();
    setCookie('start_time', $start_time, 7);
    });

// Sets timer running, updated every second.
// Start is when user first clicked 'start' button.
function activateTimer() {
    if(isCookie('start_time')) {
        x.continueTimer();
    }
    else {
        x.start();
    }
    clocktimer = setInterval(update, 1000);
}
```

The FINISH button POSTS to the `finish_from_button` controller action using AJAX:

```
  def finish_from_button
    query_string = { 
      start_time: params[:start_time], 
      finish_time: params[:finish_time] 
    }.to_query
    render js: %(window.location.href='#{new_timelog_path}?#{query_string}')
  end
```

And the `#new` action is rendered.

```
  def new
    @timelog = Timelog.new
    @timelog.start_time = params[:start_time]
    @timelog.end_time   = params[:finish_time]
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question - you can use `content_for(:include_js){ @include_js}` in view and

```
<% yield(:include_js) %> 
  <% javascript_include_tag ..... %>
<% end %>
```

in your main layout head section. Where is @include_js - boolean of your specific condition.

But I believe you shouldn't exclude js. Because js loads once and then browser uses cached copy. Use cookies to keep timer_start instead and read it by your js script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it.

1. Get the [jquery-stopwatch](https://github.com/robcowie/jquery-stopwatch) library.
2. Put it in your `public/assets/javascripts` directory
3. Add it to your application layout by putting :

   `<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.stopwatch' %>`
4. You have to store the time your timer is stopped in your database. Just fire  an event to record the `Time.now` somewhere in the database.
5. Make a helper method in your application_helper. You are trying to record the milliseconds elapsed since the timer had started. You can send  the milliseconds elapsed to the database by putting the button in a form or through AJAX. It's up to you.

   `def time_elapsed
       @time_now =  Time.now
       @time_timer_stopped = #this is where you query your db and pull out the time the timer has been stopped.
       return (@time_now - @time_timer_stopped)*1000
       #returns the miliseconds passed after you stopped the time
     end`

   6. Put this script somewhere where the `time_elapsed` method is reachable

   `$('#someDiv').stopwatch({startTime: <%= time_elapsed %>}).stopwatch('start')
   </script>`

Voila, you have your stopwatch.

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically generate start times for the timers generated by this gem? I couldn't find any reference to that in the doc.

Comment: you can make a column in your user for the timer so that you can pull out the result by simply using curent_user.timer_timestamp or something